# Evaluate conditionals at compile time in babel / webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a config file where I have a variable that can have the value X or Y depending if it's prod or dev.

I want to evaluate it at compile time.

I was able to get the NODE_ENV value from babel-plugin-transform-node-env-inline but can't figure out how to evaluate the expression. I tried babel-plugin-transform-conditionals but it throws strange code errors. Errors that don't exist.

I can evaluate at runtime since in that case both prod and dev values will be available in app.js, which I can't have.

No idea where to go from here!!

Any totally different solution would work too (like somehow compile a different file), but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about your question, you can just write the `if` statement like this

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // ...
}
```

It will be transform to

```
// or true
if (false) {
  // ...
}
```

if it is `false`, then that's a kind of unreachable code, which will be stripped by UglifyJs plugin automatically (use `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()` in your webpack config)

also don't forget to use `DefinePlugin` (and [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) if you are using windows) to declare the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable or it may not work

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
})
```

Comment: Looks like this is it. I am surprised I didn't think of using uglify to remove dead code.

Answer (score 1):

I have never use the plugin you mention. But default webpack setup should work like what I have done in the following:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var config = {
  entry: {
    ...
  },
  output: {
    ...
  },
  module: {
    ...
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      }
    }),
    // some other plugins
  ]
};
```

So the NODE_ENV is coming from your environment when you run webpack.

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --progress --hot --inline --colors --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9999",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
  }
}
```

In your package.json run the webpack in environment you specify.

**Your config.js**

```
export default {
  isDebug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  logLevel: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "error" : "info"
};
```

Another example I use in my application for redux. I only wanted to have redux-logger during development.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware";
import reducer from "./reducers";

const middleware = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? [promise(), thunk] : [promise(), thunk, logger()];

export default createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);
```

After the compile if you look at the generated code from the above redux example.

```
var middleware =  true ? [(0, _reduxPromiseMiddleware2.default)(), _reduxThunk2.default] : [(0, _reduxPromiseMiddleware2.default)(), _reduxThunk2.default, (0, _reduxLogger2.default)()];
```

`process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"` have been evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case both the possibilities are still in the compiled code, which I want to avoid. I think another user mentioned using uglify to remove dead code.

Answer (score 0):

Make one Webpack config for development, and one config for production, which you need anyway. Specify your variable in each config using the DefinePlugin, then you can reference that global variable anywhere in your bundle.